# How jaxb marshaller and unmarshallers uses generated classes

Tags: jaxb, spring-ws

I have generated classes using `wsimport/wsconsume` for my webservice. I am using JAXB marshaller and unmarshaller support. Can any one tell me how these marshaller/unmarshaller uses gnereated classes? say it is geneated - requestFile,Response File,service,ServiceSoap,ObjectFactory, Package-info. Here Service is name of my webservice.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB uses the annotations on the generated classes to reflectively marshal/unmarshal XML documents. It tries to use sensible defaults if the annotations are missing.

`package-info.java` is a weird Java5 thing, which allows you to declare package-level annotations. JAXB uses this is do things like declare package-wide type converters, or XML namespaces.

`ObjectFactory` is a generate class that provides factory methods for the various JAXB types. You usually don't need to use that yourself.

The generated service classes are used by the JAX-WS runtime to assemble the JAXB-bound model objects into actual SOAP requests and responses.

Comment: Thank you. How Soap classes will be used?

Comment: service,ServiceSoap classes. (Sorry they not really soap classes). Thank you